# How can I get count of post with django

Tags: django

I wanted to get help with this Django project. I'm trying to get the number of posts.

```
def newQuestion(request):
    template = "ask_question.html"
    form = askQuestion(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        instance.save()

        return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = askQuestion()

    context = {"form": form}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "number of posts"? is it the number of Questions asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you model name is "Question" you can try something like this,

`question_count = Question.objects.count()`